# Want to insert values into credit column with the help of cursor without using update statement

Tags: sql

Want to insert values into credit column with the help of cursor without using update statement.
when I'm doing this way then debit column gives me the correct output but credit column comes 0 because it contains negative values but the same things using update statement gives me correct answer.

1st case statement is belongs to credit column.
Rules for populating credit column:[Total-Amount if account-category=Revenue or if account-category=Asset for corresponding Expense item matched by TxnId ; 0 otherwise]

```
              CASE WHEN A.ACCOUNT_CATEGORY IN('Revenue','Asset')
              AND EXISTS (SELECT TOTAL_AMOUNT
              FROM ACCOUNTING_BOOK
              WHERE ACCOUNT_CATEGORY='Expense'
              AND TXNID=A.TXNID)
              THEN A.TOTAL_AMOUNT
              ELSE 0
              END, 

              CASE WHEN A.ACCOUNT_CATEGORY IN('Expense','Asset')
              AND EXISTS (SELECT TOTAL_AMOUNT
              FROM ACCOUNTING_BOOK
              WHERE ACCOUNT_CATEGORY='Revenue'
              AND TXNID=A.TXNID)
              THEN A.TOTAL_AMOUNT
              ELSE 0
              end);
 END LOOP;
 END;
 /
```

Comment: Add your comments to the body of your question if they add meaningful information to understand your question or where you are at.

Comment: Is it good to go?

Comment: pls give me a reply

Comment: I don't know sql. I was just helping you improving your question.

Comment: Is there anyone who can do it?